# How to understand Bayesian lasso?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, bayesian

What is the difference between Lasso and Bayesian lasso? What is the advantage of Bayesian lasso？ How to understand the Bayesian lasso intuively? I find that it is a bit hard to understand this method. Can anybody explain this a bit for me? Thank you!

Comment: This is not a traditional topic of mathematical statistics, you might get a quicker/better answer at [our sister site](https://stats.stackexchange.com)